# Double Edit ActionResult with [AllowAnonymous] and [Authorize]

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework

I have this problem: I can not create a double "Edit" ActionResult into a controller where my goal is to allow an anonymous user to change a number of fields through a filter that returns only one record in the output .... The system returns this error, and I knew, somehow, that the problem is related to the primary key.

**CONTROLLER**

```
  // GET:  
    [Authorize]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        MyTable mytable = await db.MyTable.FindAsync(id);
        if (mytable == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(mytable);
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpGet]  
    public async Task<ActionResult> EditAnonymus(int? fk_field1, string guid)
    {
        if (fk_field1 == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }


               var query = (from i in db.MyTable
                            where i.Guid == guid && i.Fk_Field1==fk_Field1
                            select new { i.Id }).SingleOrDefault();


        MyTable mytable = await db.MyTable.FindAsync(query.Id);

        if (mytable == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(mytable);
    }


    // POST: 
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [Authorize]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Edit([Bind(Include = "Id,Fk_table1,......")] MyTable mytable)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
                {
                    db.Entry(mytable).State = EntityState.Modified;
                    await db.SaveChangesAsync();
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
                catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
                {
                    Trace.Write(ex.Message);
                }


        }
        return View(mytable);
    }


    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> EditAnonymus([Bind(Include = "Id,........")] MyTable mytable)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                db.Entry(mytable).State = EntityState.Modified;
                await db.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
            {
                Trace.Write(ex.Message);
            }


        }

        return View(mytable);
    }
```

VIEW (command for entry from another View)

```
       @Html.ActionLink("Modify Anonymus",
         "EditAnonumus", controllerName: "NameController", 
          routeValues: new 
          { fk_table1 = Model.Id, guid = Request.QueryString["guid"] },   
           htmlAttributes: null)
```

VIEW (Edit)

```
    @model ManagingEvent.Models.MyTable

    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Anonymus Edit</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)

        //omiss

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Cognome, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Field, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Field, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

ERROR OUTPUT (after save)

> **Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since
>   entities were loaded. See
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=472540 for information on
>   understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.The
>   thread 0x518 has exited with code 0 (0x0).**

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is not related to the primary key but can be this line of code in the `EditAnonymus` method:

```
db.Entry(mytable).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

What you are doing is mark explicitly the entity as modified, EF will try to update it when you call `SaveChangesAsync()` and will expect to get the count of the rows updated (1), but if no properties have changed it will get 0 (no rows have been updated), therefore it will throw the exception.

I would comment that row and try to do a simple fetch-edit-save and see what happens.

Comment: Can you explain simple fetch-edit-save... sorry I have not idea.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the user449689 guidance, I searched in internet and I have found this method works:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> EditAnonymus (int? Id)
    {
        if (Id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        var TableToUpdate = await db.myTable.FindAsync(Id);
        if (TryUpdateModel(TableToUpdate, "",
           new string[] { "Field1","Field2","....","....","Field x" }))
        {
            try
            {
                db.SaveChanges();

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch (DataException /* dex */)
            {
                //Log the error (uncomment dex variable name and add a line here to write a log.
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes. Try again, and if the problem persists, see your system administrator.");
            }
        }
```